# Issue parsing Reddit XML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the reddit XML feed of a subreddit, but I'm having issues parsing it with JavaScript.

I've got this code

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    var xmlResult = "";
    $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
        xmlResult = xmlResult + ($(this).find("title").text()) + "<br />";
    });
    document.write(xmlResult);
}
```

but the issue is that it duplicates the title.

In the Reddit XML feed, there is the title and the media:title tag. I how I can fix this duplication.

Example: Title is "Really awesome title of post", and in my output I get "Really awesome title of postReally awesome title of post".

Comment: Could you add a link to the XML feed you are trying to parse?

Comment: @PierreSpring here you go: http://www.reddit.com/r/mylittlepony/new/.rss

Comment: Your code looks suspiciously similar to jQuery. If you are using a framework or library, you often don't need to write your own XML parser. If you aren't using any of these, you should post your function's code as well.

Comment: @PierreSpring I'm not, that code was from http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Comment: If you are going to use this for Javascript, why don't you use the JSON file then?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen what do you mean?

Comment: Do you know that you can get the data in JSON format? then there is no need for parsing xml!

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen no, how do you do that?

Comment: Like this: http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/.json, pretty simple and they have a page on github where you can see more: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `<item>` element contains two elements named `<title>` with identical values:

```
<item>
  <title>Really awesome title of post</title>
  ...
  <media:title>Really awesome title of post</media:title>
  ...
</item>
```

When you use the `title` selector, jQuery returns both of them and concatenates their text together.

A workaround would be to pick out the first element:

```
$(this).find("title").first().text()
```

Since the elements contain the same value anyway it doesn't matter which one you get.